# uploading large Txt files into Google Colab

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

#first question
#I am new here

thing is I am trying to upload this huge file into google colab.en.txt(text/plain) - 13113340782 bytes,  - 0% done. however its not uploading can anyone explain me or solution
I want to extract the data and split it into shards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your file to a google drive, and then load the file from your notebook.

This will then prompt you to log into your google drive account and allow access to the files.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

More detailed step by step instructions with pictures can be found here: https://www.marktechpost.com/2019/06/07/how-to-connect-google-colab-with-google-drive/